# Socket.io - Emit to array of socket id

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have socket id of each connected user stored in my database. When any user posts a comment or status, I want to broadcast the same to all his/her connections using socket id stored in my database.

I can emit the message to individual client using his/her socket id by using io.sockets.connected[ socket.id ].emit('privateMsg', 'Hello! How are you?');

But how do I emit the same to the array of socket id which i have generated using select query from my database.

Comment: Did you maintain socket id and user id array on your server.js.  As far as i know Whenever you refresh or loads page in new tab it creates new socket id

Comment: Yes, I do maintain socket id on my server.js. Whenever the page loads, i am updating the socket id for that particular user

Comment: `socketsids.forEach(function(socketid){io.to(socketid).emit(...)}`

Answer (score 7):

You can use concept of `rooms`. Whenever a socket connection arrives, join the connections to a room. And on disconnect, remove the socket from the room.

```
socket.on('connection', function () {
     socket.join('room1');
});  

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
     socket.leave('room1');
});
```

Now when you want send messages to sockets connected on a room, you can broadcast it to room.

```
socket.broadcast.to('room1').emit('eventName', data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically create a room for each socket that connects and emit to it without having to loop over the entire array every time. Like so:

```
socketids.foreach(function(socketid){io.sockets.connected[socketid].join(sendingSocket.id);});
```

Then you can emit to those sockets from your sending socket by doing the following:

```
sendingSocket.to(sendingSocket.id).emit('publicMessage', 'Hello! How are you?')
```

As a side-note, I don't think keeping socket ids that change in a database is the best approach, since they have no persistence at all. You may want to try to find a better identifier for your database.

Comment: as said by you, dynamically create a room for each socket that connects. But i already have socket id stored in my database for every connected user. Now from the database I need to get some selected users depending upon some criteria. I then need to create a room for these selected users from database. So how to create a room for the users selected from database.

Comment: A room is created when the first socket joins it. So if you need to create a room for the sockets to join, simply adapt the first code sample I gave, and a room will be generated by the socket.io library.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who visites this thread. After Socket.io 3.x we can pass arrays of room names and socket ids to io object. like this:-

```
socketIds = [xlksdf09sdfsk,sdosdifns90sdf,..........]
io.sockets.to(socketIds).emit('hello','recieving all sockets')

roomNames = [roomA,roomB]
io.to(roomNames).emit('hello','recieves each member of the rooms')
// Event is also not emmitted multiple times on the client side 
// evern if single socketId is present in multiple rooms.
```